# DMS without installation having Entity Framework driver?

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, relational-database

I'm looking for a database system to use with c#. I've mostly used SQL for now, but, this is a small applicaiton I'm gonna to create, which:

-Runs at max 1-2hours each day(so I don't want to have a SQL Server running all the time)
-Will be installed on an usb key(only requirement has to be to have .net 4.0 installed), so it has to be nomade.

What can you advise me? I search a little, but I don't how this kind of database are called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the embedded version of [Firebird](http://www.firebirdnews.org/docs/fb2min.html)

Firebird have more SQL function than SQLLite which also be a good choice but you can more easily to switch to a full version of the server

> The embedded version is an amazing variation of the server. It is a
>   fully featured Firebird server packed in just a few files. It is very
>   easy to deploy, since there is no need to install the server. It is
>   ideal for CDROM catalogs, demos or standalone desktop applications.

Here you can check [Entity Framework support](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-provider/)

Answer (score 1):

Well, i'd use a file-based "portable" database like:

- [SQLServer Ce 4.0](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc835494.aspx)
- Sqlite ([I used this provider in the past and it works well](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/), but you have [quite a bunch of options](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteWrappers)).